# An easy way to work with multiple same conception datasources in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I have two databases with only two deficiencies: URL and data, the tables are the same, even some tables's contents are the same.
I have managed two have each one as a separate datasource following this tutorial : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases .
However, code maintainability is hard, all made modifications on an entity, repository or even entity id class in one datasource have to be duplicated to the other one each time.

I am looking for configurations or practices or even ideas to make the  code maintainability easier.

using spring 2.7.4

Comment: maybe you're looking for multi-tenancy? https://www.baeldung.com/multitenancy-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: thank you, but  multi-tenancy  doesn't support my case: **multi databases one tenant** (some API calls may use two data sources)